# How to add a comma separator after each params if param has values and dot in the end of params

Tags: javascript

for example we have 3 params

```
function test(a,b,c){
  console.log(a + ',' + b + ',' + c +'.')
}

test('a','b','c')
```

will print

```
> a, b, c.
```

but in case `b` will be empty, the result will look with two comma, like

```
test('a','','c')
```

will print

```
a,,c.
```

we can improve like checking each var like this

```
function test(a,b,c){
      console.log(a + (a?',':'') + b + (b?',':'') + c +(c?'.':''))
    }
```

so now

```
 test('a','','c')
```

will print

```
a,c.
```

look ok, but when we have only b

```
test('','b','')
```

will print

```
  b,
```

and now we must to check values `a` or `b` exist and there is no `c` to print `'.'`

and complexity increases, but what if we have n vars, any ideas how to solve more easily

expected result is :

```
test('a','b','c') => a, b, c.
test('a','b','') => a, b.
test('a','','') => a.
test('','b','c') => b, c.
test('','b','') => b.
test('','','') =>
```

Comment: please add the expected output to your examples, not just the one that's "wrong"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter and use the [...rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)

```js
const isParm = prm => prm !== "" && prm !== undefined && prm !== null;

const test = (...theArgs) => {
  const list = theArgs.filter(parm => isParm(parm)); 
  if (list.length > 0) console.log(`${list.join(",")}.`)
}

let x; 
test('a','b','c')
test('a',null,'c'); // null is a falsy value
test('','','c')
test('a')
test('','b')
test(x); // undefined (falsy)
test(0,0,0); // falsy values
```

Comment: test() without any params will return `.`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your intention, this should do it.

```js
function test(...args) {
  const res = args.filter(i => i).join(',')
  return res + (res && ".")
}


// Usage
console.log(test('a','','c')); // "a,c."
console.log(test('a','b','c')); // "a,b,c."
console.log(test('','','c')); // "c."
console.log(test('a', '', '')) // "a."
console.log(test('', '', '')) // ""
```

Comment: Written like this your returned result will be either "." or ""

Comment: @Esszed yeah, I forgot the parenthesis. Updated now.

Comment: `test(0, 0, 0)` wil also show a blank

Comment: @mplungjan I only see string requirements, not numbers.

Comment: Sure... Just mentioning it

Answer (score -1):

Using an array join approach, we can add all inputs to an array.  Then filter off empty entries and join by a comma separator.

```js
function test(a,b,c) {
    var array = [a, b, c];
    return array.filter(x => x).join(", ") + ".";
}

console.log(test('a','','c'));
```

Actually, a better function signature for your function would accept an array, which allows for concat with separator of any number of items.

Comment: `but what if we have n vars` or no vars

Comment: Change the function signature to accept an array?

Comment: ...rest is recommended

Answer (score -1):

Use `Array.reduce()` function to iterate each argument in argument list and add comma separator then return final string.

```js
function test(...args){
  return args.reduce((prev, current, index) => {
    if (current.length !== 0) {
      const separator = prev.length === 0 ? "" : ",";
      prev += `${separator}${current}` 
    }
    if (index === args.length - 1) {
      prev += ".";
    }
    return prev;
  }, "");
}

console.log(test('a','','c'));
```

Comment: This is so much overkill

Comment: Nothing personal - I can write a script of 100 lines to do the same - but should I when I can use the recommended methods in 5-10 lines? It is incorrect imnho to consider reduce for this trivial issue when a filter is obviously more useful

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241616/discussion-between-mplungjan-and-rahul-kumar).